# Is there a shorthand for a function that takes no parameters and returns nothing? AKA () -> ()

Tags: swift

The title says it all, I believe. I'm simply curious if the `() -> ()` acting as a function's parameter...

```
class Test {
  var isAwesome = true
  func loadData (callback: () -> ()) {
    callback();
  }
}
```

... has a shorter version. That's it!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Swift, but it worse comes to worse I think you could just set a variable to be the empty function. Although there has to be a better answer...

Comment: What is really interesting is how should we call this function. It should have some common name like `VoidToVoid` or something like that.

Comment: Java topic: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/276859/171632

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a "Swift-way" to do it, but if you really want to shorten it:

```
typealias A = ()->() // alias this closure risking readability

class Test {
    func loadData (callback:A) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

It is a bit of a hack I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

As found in: Apple Inc. 'The Swift Programming Language'. iBooks. https://itun.es/nl/jEUH0.l
You can use the following syntax:

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: () -> ()) {
    // function body goes here
}

// here's how you call this function without using a trailing closure:

someFunctionThatTakesAClosure({
    // closure's body goes here
    })

// here's how you call this function with a trailing closure instead:

someFunctionThatTakesAClosure() {
    // trailing closure's body goes here
}
```

Comment: You could even remove the "()" after someFunctionThatTakesAClosure.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find any documentation that specifies a different solution. Every instance I can find in the current docs/book shows it how you have it. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_117) is a good section that talks about it. You can however call your method with some pretty short notation:

```
loadData {
    // ...
}
```

Rather than having to treat it as a normal parameter:

```
loadData({
    // ...
})
```

You can also call it like:

```
loadData() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no shorter-way: I can just imagine a `type-alias` (like @Benzi mentioned), but the effect seems not worth the hack.

```
func takeEmptyFunc(emptyFunc: ()->()) { emptyFunc() }

func emptyFunc() { println("Worked"); }

takeEmptyFunc() { emptyFunc() } // prints "Worked"
```